# How to solve react dom 'removeChild' on Node error while google translate extension is on and selecting any core block

Tags: block-editor, bug

console log error image

[image: error image]

I also attach video how error occur please see this https://vimeo.com/741395393

Comment: I had to register to Vimeo to watch this and it seems you're trying to use the google translate browser extension on the block editor. This isn't going to work, and there is no way for either of us to fix this without getting a job at Google and modifying the extension to work with the block editor

Comment: Thanks for answer @TomJNowell but can I update WordPress core block react js for compatible with google translate extension.

Comment: This isn't something that you can fix without modifying the google translate extension, there are no fixes on the WordPress side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This cannot be fixed from the WordPress side, it requires changes from the Google Translate team to work with WordPress' block editor. **Only Google can do that.**

If you need to translate the content of a post it can't be done from inside the editor using a browser extension unless that browser extension was specifically built to work with WordPress.